# Как сделать input range с центром 0 и одинаковыми значениями min и max

Tags: javascript, input, range

Искал на просторах сети информацию, как реализовать такой ползунок, чтобы была возможность двигать его из центра вправо и влево, но чтобы в центре было значение 0, а справа и слева максимальное значение было бы 10.

Может кто то уже делал с помощью `JS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min="-10"` - минимальное значение

`max="10"` - максимальное значение

`value="0"` - значение по умолчанию

`step="1"` - шаг

```css
output {border: 1px solid gray; color: black; font-size: 14px; padding: 2px 4px; border-radius: 3px;} div {margin: 20px 0;}
```

```html
<div>1
<input class="range" type="range" min="-10" max="10" value="0" step="1" onmousemove="rangevalue.value=value" />
<output id="rangevalue">0</output>
</div>

<div>2
<input class="range1" type="range" min="-10" max="10" value="0" step="1" oninput="rangevalue1.value=value" />
<output id="rangevalue1">0</output>
</div>

<div>3
<input class="range2" type="range" min="-10" max="10" value="0" step="1" oninput="rangevalue2.value=Math.abs(value)" />
<output id="rangevalue2">0</output>
</div>

<div>4
<input class="range3" type="range" min="-10" max="10" value="0" step="1" list="rangelist" onchange="document.getElementById('rangevalue3').innerHTML = this.value;" />
<output id="rangevalue3">0</output>
<datalist id="rangelist">
<option value="0" label="0">
</option><option value="-10" label="-10">
</option><option value="10" label="10">
</option></datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Сейчас попросят, чтобы процент шёл из центра, как "баланс". Сейчас процент заполнения слева до середины.

Comment: Исходя из вопроса, значение по модулю выводить надо.

Comment: А что бы не было отрицательное значение я так понимаю надо в JS преобразовать в положительное или же можно как то задать значения в HTML?

Comment: @liquid: модуль - `rangevalue.value=Math.abs(value)`

Comment: @UModeL Спасибо, подскажи пожалуйста как вписать это и куда что бы в output  отображалось положительное значение.

Comment: Блин всё понял, Спасибо)

Comment: А почему используется `onmousemove`, а не `oninput`? Оно же постоянно генерируется при перемещении курсора, даже если ползунок не был сдвинут. К тому же оно _не_ генерируется, если двигать ползунок с помощью клавиатуры.

Comment: А как вывести второй output , что бы они были по разным сторонам и каждый показывал свое значение, если я двигаю в право отображался правый output если в лево левый?

Comment: @Sevastopol' да я по вашему примеру сделал такую вещь

Comment: <div>
<input class="range" type="range" min="-10" max="10" value="0" step="0.5" list="rangelist" onmousemove="rangevalue.value=Math.abs(value)" />
<output id="rangevalue">0</output>
<output id="rangevalue1">0</output>

Comment: Но почему то во втором не отображается значение

Comment: Создал два output с разными ID, стилизовать каждый получается а вот со значениями запара